# Columnizer is dividing columns unequally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Columnizer is dividing columns unequally (having spaces in first and second column) when using it with the divs and sub divs. below script i am using to call columnize function.

```
 $('.nav-menuSub > a:first-child').addClass('dontend');
            $('.menuSub-list').columnize({
                width : 200, //per column width
                //height : 550
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using display:none css with the sub div. columnizer does not consider display:none CSS. Just removing that CSS solved the issue.